# How to center align a single plot within a row of groupplot

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I have an odd number of plots, 5, and would like to center align this fifth plot using groupplot as well as a group x-axis label. I have a 3x2 setup. I searched for answers and I've seen a case where someone used stackengine and separate axis environments, however I want to keep the groupplot titles and I find the coding is more organised especially with the amount of plots. If you have any suggestions please advise, otherwise please help me center the last plot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.2pt]{standalone}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\DeclareSIUnit{\molar}{M}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
rows=3,
columns=2,
horizontal sep=50pt,
vertical sep=50pt
},
    xlabel={},
    ylabel={},
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left,
scaled x ticks=real:1e-6,
xtick scale label code/.code={},
]
\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(a)}]
\addplot [only marks, mark=o]  {x^2};\label{raw}
\addplot [smooth] {x^3}; \label{fit}
\coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1); 

\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(b)}]
\addplot [only marks, mark=o] {x^2}; 

\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(c)}]
\addplot [only marks, mark=o] {x^2}; 

\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(d)}]
\addplot [only marks, mark=o] {x^2}; 
\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(c)}]
\addplot [only marks, mark=o] {x^2};
\coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);  

\end{groupplot}
\node at ($(group c1r1.west)!0.5!(group c1r2.west)$)[xshift=-1.2cm]{\rotatebox{90}{\Large{$\Delta$y}}};
\node at ($(group c1r3.south)!0.5!(group c1r3.south)$)[yshift=-1cm]{\Large{$x$}}};

\path (top|-current bounding box.north)--
  coordinate(legendpos)
  (bot|-current bounding box.north);
\matrix[
matrix of nodes,
anchor=south,
draw,
inner sep=0.2em,
draw
]at([yshift=1ex]legendpos)
{
\ref{raw}& data points &[5pt]
\ref{fit}& fitted curve\\};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

Inside a `groupplot`, each plot is named `group c<number>r<number>`, where the last part indicates the column and row number, respectively, for the plot. Using this, you can use the `calc` library to place the last plot, using for example

```
\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(c)},
  at = { ($ ( $ (group c1r2.south west) + (0,-100pt)$ )!0.5!(group c2r2.south east) $ ) }]
```

The code (I suppressed an spurious closing brace in the last `\node`'s text and also changed `\Large{...}` to `{\Large...}`):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.2pt]{standalone}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\DeclareSIUnit{\molar}{M}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
rows=3,
columns=2,
horizontal sep=50pt,
vertical sep=50pt
},
    xlabel={},
    ylabel={},
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left,
scaled x ticks=real:1e-6,
xtick scale label code/.code={},
]
\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(a)}]
\addplot [only marks, mark=o]  {x^2};

\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(b)}]
\addplot [only marks, mark=o] {x^2}; 

\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(c)}]
\addplot [only marks, mark=o] {x^2}; 

\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(d)}]
\addplot [only marks, mark=o] {x^2}; 
\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(e)},
  at = { ($ ( $ (group c1r2.south west) + (0,-100pt)$ )!0.5!(group c2r2.south east) $ ) }]
\addplot [only marks, mark=o] {x^2};  

\end{groupplot}
\node[xshift=-1.2cm] at 
  ($(group c1r1.west)!0.5!(group c1r2.west)$)
  {\rotatebox{90}{{\Large $\Delta$y}}};
\node[yshift=-1cm] 
  at (group c1r3.south)
  {{\Large$x$}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick response. However, I would like to keep the global x-axis, is there another way to have that? It was also part of the initial request and is quite relevant. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh Doesn't my answer keep it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your edit till now, it works great! Thanks so much again. you seem to be my latex savior, haha. :)

Comment: @SpencerTrinh :) You're welcome!

Comment: hi, one more thing please. Is there a way to align a external legend using the matrix? I found that code on this site, but I can't seem to tweak it so that it is aligned correctly.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh You don't mention how are you building your legend nor where do you want it to appear; furthermore, since this is not directly related to the problem addressed here (centering the fifth plot), I think the best thing to do is to open a fresh new question for the new requirement.